# SAPUI5 switch focus

Tags: javascript, focus, sapui5

In my code I have textarea and dropdown input with binded model data.
When changing dropdown value textarea gets new value and changes its content.
Problem is that I would like to focus to switch from dropdown to textarea.

Currently I have modified liveChange event like this:

```
flavorScriptsDDLB.liveChange = function(ev) {
    _scriptModel.setProperty("@selectedScript", textArea.getValue());
    _scriptModel.setSelectedScriptID(ev.getSource().getSelectedKey());
    textArea.setEnabled(true);
    textArea.focus();
};
```

but still dropdown keeps the focus instead of switching it to textarea.
Found relative Question here, but it was unanswered also.

Comment: Did you do any debugging with browser tools?  Also where is textArea defined...globally?

Comment: Yes. I also tried to launch jQuery blur on that dropdown. the textArea is defined in the same file.

Comment: How will textArea be accessible via your call back function?  You may want to try `var textArea = sap.ui.getCore().byId("yourtextarea");` inside your callback function...So there weren't any javascript errors in the console when you debugged?

Comment: I moved textArea definition before dropdown definition so that it would be initialised, but now I'm confused why the callback is not called at all. And no errors in console etc. But now I can click on textarea and it will get focus right away not after double click.

Comment: I meant that your variable textArea might not be accessible in your call back function so you might want to do something like this: `sap.ui.getCore().byId("textareaid").setEnabled(true);` and `sap.ui.getCore().byId("textareaid").focus();` also you would need to change your `_scriptModel` calls in the same way...I would also print to the console when the method is called like this: `console.log(ev);` and `console.log(sap.ui.getCore().byId("textareaid");` put those to lines first in the callback function to make sure your objects are there...

Comment: I modified my code so that both variables are declared inside callback function, but after applying focus() method the dropdown still keeps focus (when pressing any key it acts as look for suggestions inside dropdown instead of writing text into textArea). It looks like two elements have focus at the same time (textArea has its blinking cursor and dropdown has selected value colored)

Comment: Hmmm...that is strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The re-rendering of the changed TextArea is done in a Timeout, add a timeout of your own to set focus:

See this for example: http://jsbin.com/cudogopuye/1/edit?html,js,output